# render sqllite data in html view with ionic2

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I make a select query against the database and read the results from the logcat and see the data there. But the issue is,its not able to render in the html view after binding

```
//data retrieve section
db.executeSql('select * from users', {}).then((data) => {
    this.items = [];
    if(data.rows.length > 0) {
        for(var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
            this.items.push({name: data.rows.item(i)});
        }
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<ion-item href="#" *ngFor="let x of items" >
    {{x.fname}}
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You create the property **name** in your object and you are trying to call **fname** in your HTML. So change `{{x.fname}}` to `{{x.name}}`.